# How to remove the remove button in kendo ui upload filename

Tags: kendo-ui

i trying to remove the remove button in kendo ui upload filename. Please advise.

I have tried this one from the post but not working

```
.k-upload .k-upload-action {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I've just tried and it works! Check it here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/NwB62/1/

Comment: Thanks OnaBai for your feedback. It is work

Comment: Um! your code works but you have accepted one answer saying that your code works? I would say that it was actually not a problem and the question should be closed, wouldn't you?

Comment: Yes OnaBai. I would agree with you. Appreantly, it does not work when i posted on the question. Then after i saw your answer, i retried again and it work and i did not i missed in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested this and it work for me, so I would imagine that you're encountering an issue somewhere with CSS specificity. Try making the CSS rule more specific, for example:

```
ul.k-upload-files .k-upload-action {
    display: none;
}
```